# Arbitrary union example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In *Enderton, Elements of Set Theory*, an ***arbitrary union*** axiom is written in this way.

**Axiom.** For any set $A$, there exist a set $B$ whose elements are exactly the members of the members of $A$.
\begin{equation}
\forall x  \left[x \in B \iff \left(\exists b \in A\right)x \in b\right].
\end{equation}
This set is called $\cup A$. Hence,
\begin{equation}
x \in \cup A \iff \left(\exists b \in A\right)x \in b.
\end{equation}

I have **two doubts**:

1. Now, suppose that $A=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. Then, $\cup A$ is the set of 
   members of members of $A$. Members of $A$ are $\{x\}$ and $\{x,y\}$. Hence, $\cup A=\{x,x,y\}=\{x,y\}$. What about $\cup \cup A$? It should be the set of members of $x$ and $y$. Thereby $\cup \cup A= x \cup y$? Is it okay?
2. Suppose $A=\{x,\{x,y\}\}$. Now I'm really in trouble. What is $\cup A$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A$ is a set with two elements, then $\bigcup A$ is the union of these two elements.

1. $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ has two elements, so $\bigcup\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}=\{x\}\cup\{x,y\}=\{x,y\}$.
2. $\{x,y\}$ has two elements, so $\bigcup\{x,y\}$ is indeed $x\cup y$.
3. How many elements does $\{x,\{x,y\}\}$ have? Well, two: $x$ and $\{x,y\}$. Therefore $\bigcup\{x,\{x,y\}\}$ equals...

Comment: Asaf, just aside about notation. Isn't $\cup A$ preferable above $\bigcup A$? Personally I use $\cup$ as operator on sets $a\mapsto\cup a$ and $\bigcup$ comes in as abbrevation: $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i=\cup\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$. What is your policy on this? Just curious.

Comment: No, $\bigcup$ is the $\sum$ when $\cup$ is $+$.

Comment: So the same symbol on both sides then: $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i=\bigcup\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$? I feel reluctant.

Comment: Yes. And the choice of which one to use is up to you, and your space constraints (vertical and horizontal). Just like $$\int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{[0,1]} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Thank you. I will think about it.

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, that's correct.
2. It's $x\cup\{x, y\} $, the set of all elements inside $x$ and the elements $x$ and $y$ themselves.